# Sitecore instance Crashing - What is the best tool to analyze the memory dump?

Tags: memory-leaks, crash, sitecore

I am finding the Sitecore CD instance server is going down, I have the memory dump of PROD server, I want to analyze the memory. What are the best tools you recommend to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/fremag/MemoScope.Net

There are other tools like, DebugDiag and WinDbg